# Why is dotenv appending " #tunnel" to my variable?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv, tunnel

I have a `.env` file which contains:

`POSTGRESQL_URL=localhost`

The first two lines of code executed are:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

At this point, `process.env.POSTGRESQL_URL` contains the value `localhost #tunnel`.

Why is this happening? This incorrect value prevents `pg` connecting to it.

(It is true that I have a tunnel open on localhost on a particular port, but that doesn't seem relevant? Certainly this behaviour is not helpful to me. Also, this behaviour seems to persist even when the tunnel is killed.)

Comment: Did you try localhos, ocalhost, xxxyyyzzz or 127.0.0.1 and see #tunnel persists?

Comment: Oops, thanks. Turns out it was loading the .env file I thought it was. The `localhost #tunnel` was actually the complete line from the real .env file - looks like dotenv doesn't support comments on the same line.

Comment: See rules section
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv